# How do I use an async workflow in a Seq.pick in F#

Tags: f#, async-workflow

I am new to functional programming in general and started learning F# recently. I wanted to use an async workflow returning `Async<'U option>` to pick an item in a Sequence. I find a nice `Seq.pick` function, but I am not sure how I could use that with an async workflow.

If that is not possible, is there another alternative to using an imperative style program to pick the item from the list. The following is a modified variation of my program. Any feedback is highly appreciated.

```
let run = async {
    while not stopped do
        use! resource = acquireResourceLockAsync
        let! items = fetchItemsAsync 5
        let! item = Seq.pick returnIfLocked items
        let! status = performTaskAsync item
        do! updateStatusAsync status
        do! Async.Sleep 1000
    }
```

Thanks in anticipation.

**EDIT**: Updated my question based on the answer by jpalmer. I noticed both `Seq.filter` and `Seq.pick` earlier and decided that `Seq.pick` will meet my need better, as I need the first item that I am able to lock. However, I forgot to change the return value of my function - instead of returning `true`, it should return `Some(item)`. Now with that update, is there an elegant way to approach this without 1) blocking a thread to convert `Async<'U option>` to `'U` and 2) resorting to an imperative style looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unclear exactly what you are trying to do.  If you want to convert from `Async<'T>` to `'T` non-blocking, then you want to use `let!` in an async workflow.  So the seq-like logic probably needs to be written as its own loop, as suggested below.  If that doesn't help, then perhaps share more code, especially the intended types of items/item/returnIfLocked, as I'm unclear what's async in your example.

```
let asyncPick f (s:seq<_>) =
    async {
        use e = s.GetEnumerator()
        let r = ref None
        while Option.isNone(!r) && e.MoveNext() do
            let! x = f e.Current
            r := x
        match !r with
        | Some z -> return z
        | None -> return failwith "no matching item found"
    }

let chooser ax =
    async {
        let! x = ax
        if x%3 = 0 then
            return Some x
        else
            return None
    }

let s = seq { for i in 1..10 do yield async { return i } }

let main() =
    async {
        let! firstChosen = s |> asyncPick chooser
        return firstChosen
    } 
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> printfn "%d"

main()
```

Comment: I got the point that I have to implement my own pickAsync routine. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to look at the signature of the function you are using,

`Seq.pick` expects a function which returns `option<'t>`, you want to use `Seq.Filter` which takes a function which returns a bool.

You will still have another problem though in that you have `Async<bool>` - you will need to convert that to a normal `bool`, but you could do this inside your 'Seq.Filter' function

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the question with new info. I can't use Seq.filter as I need the first item that satisfies the lock. Also I can't perform the lock function on all items and throw the rest away. Hence I must use Seq.pick. However is there an elegant way to convert `Async<option<'t>>` to `option<'t>` without blocking a thread?

Comment: @Charles Prakash Dasari You cannot possibly convert from `Async<'t>` to `'t` without blocking your thread - when the object is an `Async<'t>`, the computation hasn't been done.  If you want just the first result you can use `Seq.Find` rather than `Seq.Filter`

Comment: Yes, I realize that. My basic question was to perform pick/find using an async function as its input. I realize from Brian's response that I have to implement my own pickAsync routine. Thanks for the help.